# Node.js - Multiple websocket servers?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I've got a system running mainly PHP for server-sided logic, however, I am using Node.js for a few parts of the system and I've got a question about what the best way to handle this is.

The Node.js server is used solely as a websocket server. I'm using Socket.IO as the API for the sockets.

Currently I have three different uses for the sockets, i.e. A queue to handle incoming requests, a chat server and an announcements system.

My question is; is this the best approach? The file looks messy, all my logic is in the single file. Should I spread this out to separate files to handle each part, OR, should I be creating multiple socket servers to handle the different uses?

With this current implementation, i'm finding it very hard to debug any failures, as there seems to be too much happening in the one script.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is down to preference and the size of your system.

Personally I would at least separate the logic for each component into separate modules.  That way at least each bit is kind of self contained and the system can become modular.  In my opinion this makes it far easier to maintain and add/remove components.

Running multiple socket servers could be a bit overkill if your app is small, however if your having trouble separating the data to be handled by each part it could be worth considering running more than one.